# ErrorDocument, remove .php and force https .htacces

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://demo.com/404

#Remove .php
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ $1.php    

#Force https and without www
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This isn't work ErrorDocument 404, I want you to do this:

www.demo.com -> https://demo.com

www.demo.com/page-not-exits -> https://demo.com/404

www.demo.com/page.php -> https://demo.com/page

http://demo.com -> https://demo.com

Greetings and thank you!

### Solution

Finally this works:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
#errorredirect
ErrorDocument 404 http://demo.com/404.php
#remove .php 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

thanks @rushil-pachchigar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
#errorredirect
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com/404.php
#remove .php 
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+(.+?)\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=302,NE,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !POST
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)index\.php$ /$1 [L,R=302,NC,NE]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Ok, I'm working almost perfect, but this situation does not: `https://www.demo.com -> https://demo.com` thank you very much!

Comment: here only remove RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301] www. and try once

Comment: Finally I added this and it works fine:                                                  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_SCHEME}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

Comment: Hi @rushil-pachchigar, I have a problem, when I put it `https://www.demo.com/demo/demo` shows this http://image.prntscr.com/image/4a42f437a15c45a7867208d81551c4d6.png

Comment: Do you have demo/demp.php ?

Comment: I do not have it.

Comment: yessssss, after 404 error you can add these two line and check once

Comment: ErrorDocument 500 http://example.com/404.php, ErrorDocument 403 http://example.com/404.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following htaccess

```
ErrorDocument 404 https://demo.com/404
RewriteEngine on
#force https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://demo.com/$1 [L,NE,R]
 #remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below rules,

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ 404 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([\w-]+) $1.php [L]
```